# PostgreSQL: Sorting the rows based on value of a JSON in an array of JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-12

A table says `products` have a JSONB column called `identifiers` that stores an array of JSON objects.

*Sample data in products*

```
 id  |     name    |      identifiers
-----|-------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1  | umbrella    | [{"id": "productID-umbrella-123", "domain": "ecommerce.com"}, {"id": "amzn-123", "domain": "amzn.com"}]
  2  | ball        | [{"id": "amzn-234", "domain": "amzn.com"}]
  3  | bat         | [{"id": "productID-bat-234", "domain": "ecommerce.com"}]
```

Now, I have to write a query that sorts the elements in the table based on the "id" value for the domain "amzn.com"

Expected result

```
 id   |     name     |      identifiers
----- |--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3   | bat          |  [{"id": "productID-bat-234", "domain": "ecommerce.com"}]
  1   | umbrella     |  [{"id": "productID-umbrella-123", "domain": "ecommerce.com"}, {"id": "amzn-123", "domain": "amzn.com"}]
  2   | ball         |  [{"id": "amzn-234", "domain": "amzn.com"}]
```

ids of `amzn.com` are "amzn-123" and "amzn-234".
When sorted by ids of amzn.com "amzn-123" appears first, followed by "amzn-234"

Ordering the table by values of "id" for the domain "amzn.com",
record with id 3 appears first since the id  for amzn.com is NULL,
followed by a record with id 1 and 2, which has a valid id that is sorted.

I am genuinely clueless as to how I could write a query for this use case.
If it were a JSONB and not an array of JSON I would have tried.

Is it possible to write a query for such a use case in PostgreSQL?
If yes, please at least give me a pseudo code or the rough query.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one "amazon ID"?

Comment: No, there will not.
But we don't have any schema restrictions. Even if there are multiple ids, I don't mind taking in one and ignoring the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't know the position in the array, you will need to iterate over all array elements to find the amazon ID.

Once you have the ID, you can use it with an `order by`. Using `nulls first` puts those products at the top that don't have an amazon ID.

```
select p.*, a.amazon_id
from products p
   left join lateral (
      select item ->> 'id' as amazon_id
      from jsonb_array_elements(p.identifiers) as x(item)
      where x.item ->> 'domain' = 'amzn.com'
      limit 1 --<< safe guard in case there is more than one amazon id
   ) a on true --<< we don't really need a join condition
order by a.amazon_id nulls first;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=746e41f6fca32178de1b7375fa6f1b74)

---

With Postgres 12 this would be a bit shorter:

```
select p.*
from products p
order by jsonb_path_query_first(identifiers, '$[*] ? (@.domain == "amzn.com").id') nulls first
```

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. You have helped me many times. #Respect.

Comment: My local is Postgres 12, both the answers were very helpful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After few tweaks, this is the query that finally made it,

```
select p.*, amzn -> 'id' AS amzn_id
from products p left join lateral JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(p.identifiers) amzn ON amzn->>'domain' = 'amzn.com' 
order by amzn_id nulls first
```